# How do the Dominion members regard the Prophets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

I'm mainly interested in the Founders, but also the Breen, Vorta, and Jem'Hadar.

Do they consider them to be mythical? Impressive? Not worth their attention?

Comment: I guess they aren't terribly happy with them.

Comment: it's not likely they knew of them, at least not until after contact with the Alpha quadrant - certainly not the Gamma quadrant races. The Breen were Alpha Quadrant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The Dominion: "superstitious nonsense"

Weyoun expresses the opinion of the Founders and the Vorta on the Prophets most acutely:

> WEYOUN: I'm not sure how much faith I have in this — what did he call it?
>
> DAMAR: A Pah Wraith.
>
> WEYOUN: ***Pah Wraiths and Prophets. All this talk of gods strikes me as nothing more than superstitious nonsense.***
>
> DAMAR: You believe that the Founders are gods, don't you?
>
> WEYOUN: That's different.
>
> DAMAR: In what way?
>
> WEYOUN: The Founders *are* gods.

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/550.htm))

As far as I am aware, the Jem'Hadar and Breen have expressed no particular opinion on the Prophets, at least in canon.

Comment: Was Weyoun also speaking for the Founders here?

Comment: @T-1000'sSon : I'm assuming the opinion of the Founders is of little substantive difference.  If the Founders believed the Prophets to be any more than superstitious nonsense, they may have taken more of an interest into what happened to their fleet in the wormhole.

Comment: Weyoun certainly is NOT speaking for the founders, that would be out of character completely.  However, Praxis's comment is also likely accurate.